# Replacing a light with a ceiling fan. The fan has five wires. I only have a power wire & neutral wire coming from my box. What to do with the others?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Wiring diagram for the ceiling fan.Harbor Breeze Centreville 42" model# 41239,40689,40687,40688/ item# 0732082,0807429,0807432,0807433 I also have some images of the top side of the fan to make it easier to visualize the wiring.It would only allow me to post the one pic at a time

Comment: Did the fan not come with any instructions?

Comment: Yes but it assumes the house wiring has more than two wires

Comment: I read some comments on a similar situation. So I know it doesn't matter if ground the fan to the box. I don't know which wires to combine

Comment: Is it a fan with a light? Does it have pull chain switches? Remote? What color are the wires?

Comment: The fan has a light and two pull cords. The wires are red, orange, yellow, white and black. On the light kit the wires are black and white

Comment: No remote with the fan

Comment: Name and model # of the fan  or take a picture of the wiring diagrams from the instructions please.

Comment: Yes, can you get us a make and model for this fan? I suspect it may be missing some parts...

Comment: Charles, please make it easy for us to help you by showing us what instructions you have and where specifically you're getting stuck. Having 5 wires is uncommon, and the colors of the wires' insulation in an appliance doesn't always have a specific meaning. Edit your question (don't reply with another comment) and use the button with 'mountains' on it to add one or more pics.

Comment: A grounded system means a bare copper, this can be added from another source if fed from the same panel but we usually just mount it to the box as fan rated boxes are metal. You only have 1 power source so the fan motor and the lights will have the same hot and neutral.

Comment: I will get you a copy of it as soon as I get home from work. I work at the Mill and we are in the middle of a cold mill shutdown. 15-18 hr days for the past 4 days.

Comment: https://doc-08-8s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/aj04774ble8rcmtonnlkiop34qqpaom2/vfflse2uarjgkmg3e7u0u5macn9002vr/1651940550000/02368561946197556004/08591341196748628451Z/1Ot04HVCw_C0343Xyj3gInRgGziks072F?e=download&nonce=mlh6p0r0mgej6&user=08591341196748628451Z&hash=fs83f61kah1o8ab2mu5ofbquvju6tkhm

Comment: "The Black wire is hot power for the fan. The White wire is common for the fan and light kit. The Blue wire is hot power for light. The Green wire is the ground wire." *"The wires are red, orange, yellow, white and black"* - uh, you got shipped something that belongs in another country? Wire color doesn't match up: call customer support. "1-800-643-0067, 8 a.m. - 6 p.m., EST, Monday - Thursday, 8 a.m. - 5 p.m., EST, Friday."

Comment: *"No remote with the fan"* - with those wack colors, it sure sounds like it should have one... Fan that came in the box is in the wrong box and doesn't have its remote sensor? "make and model [on its nameplate] for this fan?"